# Can I Get Individual Session Data from Google Universal Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, collaborative-filtering

I'm trying to add recommender systems to an existing website.  In particular, I'd like to implement item-item collaborative filtering, to figure out what pages users tend to visit in the same session--much like Amazon's "People who viewed this item also viewed...."

At a minimum, collaborative filtering requires data on each individual viewing session, so that the algorithm can determine which pages get viewed *together*, rather than just tallying up how many times each page gets viewed in the aggregate.

If I were creating a new website, I could pretty easily add code to collect this data.  However, this is an existing website, and has been set up to use Google Universal Analytics.

I have two questions:

1. Can I get Universal Analytics Data through an API?  I need to be able to analyze the data using my own algorithms, not just look at it in a dashboard.  I know about the Core Reporting API--but the Core Reporting API doesn't seem to include any extra Universal Analytics variables.  I know about the API for *sending* Universal Analytics data, but that's not what I'm trying to do here.
2. Assuming I can query an API or otherwise export the Universal Analytics data, will I be able to distinguish individual sessions?  The idea here is not to ask questions about individual users (let alone associate their data with some other data), but simply to figure out which pages were viewed in the same sessions.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Google Analytics Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/) many combinations of the available [Dimensions and Metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/). You should check out the [Common Queries page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/common-queries) to get a sense of how precise you can get in terms of how people might use your application.

Also the [Hello Analytics APIs Quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/) is a good place to start if you haven't developed an application with Google APIs.

Comment: Matt, looking at the "Common Queries" page, all the queries I see involve aggregate numbers:  total pageviews or sessions, total sessions broken down by device, etc.  I've also read, in multiple place, that the old Google Analytics, while it collects data on individual sessions, doesn't provide users any way to access them.  I'm just curious if Universal Analytics is any different.